# Cant add using Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid namespace

Tags: xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to use the Telerik RadDataGrid in my project. For starting off I have just copied the code given the "Telerik Controls Example" app. But when I try adding the namespace "using Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid" I get an error
"The name "RadDataGrid" does not exist in the namespace "using:Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid".

I have been able to use the RadCustomHubTile easily till now but RadDataGrid is giving me problems. RadDataGrid does not appear in the toolbox also.

I have added Rad Controls for Windows 8 in the reference section.

I am using C#, xaml, visual studio 2012 and trying to build a windows 8 app.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanx :)

Comment: Hi Vanya, have you solved the problem? Could you please post some code, and make sure you have the latest release of the controls.

Comment: Hi @IrisClasson Sorry for the late reply! I had solved my problem by adding the latest release :) Thanx!

Comment: Close question please (add answer by yourself and mark as answer after a few days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who do not know the answer here it is.

Just add this namespace: `xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"`

And in no time you can be using `<telerik:RadGridView />`!!!!